# function inside for loop errors out in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

Array length is 4,when i ran the loop for 3, it runs fine without any errors. But when i run the for loop for 4 times it errors out.

```
for(var userI=0;userI<userArray.length;userI++) {

    var userEmail = userArray[userI].UserEmail;
    var userFName = userArray[userI].FirstName;
    var userMName = userArray[userI].MiddleName;
    var userLName = userArray[userI].LastName;
    //Check for the user and create the user if the user is not created.
    (function (uEmail,uFName,uMName,uLName) {
        logger.info("FirstName inside the function::"+tFName);
        //Check and create user
        queryUserEmail(uEmail).then(function (checkFlag) {
            if (checkFlag === true) {
                //User already Exists, Log it
                logger.info('User '+uEmail+' already Existed');
            } else {
                CreateClassElements.click();
                //Now create user
                createUserPage.createUser(uEmail,uFName,uMName,uLName);
            };
            //Clear the element
            emailQueryElement.clear();
        });
    }(userEmail,userFName,userMName,userLName));
};
```

When i run the loop without the **queryUserEmail** function it runs fine for 4 times

```
for(var userI=0;userI<userArray.length;userI++) {

    var userEmail = userArray[userI].UserEmail;
    var userFName = userArray[userI].FirstName;
    var userMName = userArray[userI].MiddleName;
    var userLName = userArray[userI].LastName;
    //Check for the user and create the user if the user is not created.
    (function (uEmail,uFName,uMName,uLName) {
        logger.info("FirstName inside the function::"+uEmail);   
    }(userEmail,userFName,userMName,userLName));
};
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have what looks to be a typo:

```
CreateClassElements..click();
```

Perhaps that segment of the code is only running on the 4th iteration.

Comment: sorry, edited the typo. its not only that. Whwnever i use queryUserEmail(), it fails on the last loop.

Comment: What is the error? Which line? Can you reproduce a working subset in jsfiddle?

Comment: finally figured it out, since the function is running as Asynchronous, it errors out in 4th loop because of the issue in the page element load time. So, i put a wait time and it started working.